# HTML <body onload=""> doesn't stop

Tags: javascript, html

I've got the following

```
<body onload="document.myform.submit()">
```

and it doesnt stop submitting the form. I think everytime it submits the form the page loads again and it submits it again and so on. how do i stop it?

**edit:** my form is an empty form im submiting it just to involke my action class into putting data in request and then redirecting back to my jsp page again for the page to display it, so i want it to submit as soon as the page loads.

Comment: If your form is posting back to the same page...

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, you've created an infinite loop.

How to stop it? Remove it from onload on the body.

Not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish here though.

*** Update (in response to your update) ***

I'd recommend using AJAX to post in this case.

Take a look at jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

When you submit the form, the browser navigates to whatever page the server sends back.
If that page submits the form again, you'll get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think your explanation of the cause is correct.

It's easy to fix: Just remove your onload attribute. It makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 0):

If the form on your page is posting to the page it is on, then yes, it will non stop submit.

What are you trying to achieve exactly?  Probably best to remove the onload line, or change the action of the form element to an alternative location.
[image]

**Edit**

As per your edit, consider an AJAX request on a timer.  This would be much less obtrusive to the user.

Comment: @user521180 What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I want to call my dopost() function in my servelet class so it puts data in request for my .jsp page to display it. when the page is first loaded, it is empty because the servlets has not been called. its only called when i submit the form. so i want the form to submit as soon as  load the page. its the way its done everywhere i think

Comment: Have you thought about using a querystring?

Comment: no need for timer, just fetch data using AJAX in the onload =)

Answer (score 0):

Whats in the rest of the HTML ? specifically the `<form>` tag ?

Comment: Please don't post comments in the answers section. You can ask OP something by posting a comment below the question.